# How to use centroid option in Field Calculator in QGis

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, centroids

I want to use Centroid option in field calculator in QGis .How to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this post as a very similar question was asked:

[Using Field Calculator in QGIS to update columns with centroid coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/using-field-calculator-in-qgis-to-update-columns-with-centroid-coordinates)

Seems back then it wasn't possible to use field calculator in this way for polygons,  but Underdark published a work round.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing if there's a 'real' answer (without a workaround) to this question now, as I see there's a 'centroid' function in the field calculator which I don't think was there before. However, I played with it, and am also unclear on the syntax. Perhaps there is a better answer to this question after all, using 1.9.0 Master.)

Answer (score -2):

right-click on vector layer in TOC --> open attribute table --> toggle editing mode (blue pencil icon) --> open field calculator

have you seen the following post: [How to determine the centroid of polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45243/how-to-determine-the-centroid-of-polygons)

Comment: that and all even i know but inside field calculator what sql command i should give i am asking that?